# Mono 2.10.1 apache errors: Command stream corrupted, last command was -1

Tags: apache, mono, apache2, mod-mono

When starting a test mono server, Immediately the site is giving quite a few errors. The error I'm particularly concerned about is

```
[error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
[error] Command stream corrupted, last command was -1
```

since it happens about a dozen times on start, and then once or more per page request. any ideas what's causing that?
Also , the error

```
No access to the given key
```

is occurring despite the fact I explicitly set `MONO_REGISTRY_PATH` to a directory owned by `www-data`, and I even tried `chmod 777 -R` once. Any help here would be great. The full error log from restart is below.

```
[Wed Mar 16 10:32:42 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.5 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8k mod_mono/2.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
Listening on: /tmp/mod_mono_server_global
Root directory: /
Listening on: /tmp/mod_mono_server_global
Root directory: /
Listening on: /tmp/mod_mono_server_global
Root directory: /
Error: Address already in use
Error: Address already in use
mod-mono-server4
Listening on: /tmp/mod_mono_server_www.tunewiki.com
Root directory: /srv/www/tunewikiweb
mod-mono-server4
Listening on: /tmp/mod_mono_server_www.tunewiki.com
Root directory: /srv/www/tunewikiweb
Error: There's already a server listening on /tmp/mod_mono_server_www.tunewiki.com
[Wed Mar 16 10:32:48 2011] [error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
[Wed Mar 16 10:32:48 2011] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was -1
... (several lines) ...
[Wed Mar 16 10:34:24 2011] [error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
[Wed Mar 16 10:34:24 2011] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was -1
(info) Auto generated encryption keys not saved: System.Security.SecurityException: No access to the given key
  at Microsoft.Win32.KeyHandler..ctor (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rkey, System.String basedir, Boolean is_volatile) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Win32.KeyHandler..ctor (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rkey, System.String basedir) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Win32.KeyHandler.Lookup (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rkey, Boolean createNonExisting) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Win32.UnixRegistryApi.OpenSubKey (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rkey, System.String keyname, Boolean writable) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey (System.String name, Boolean writable) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey:OpenSubKey (string,bool)
  at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeyRegistryStorage.OpenRegistryKey (System.String path, Boolean write) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeyRegistryStorage.Store (System.Byte[] buf, KeyType kt) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
(info) Auto generated encryption keys not saved: System.Security.SecurityException: No access to the given key
  at Microsoft.Win32.KeyHandler..ctor (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rkey, System.String basedir, Boolean is_volatile) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Win32.KeyHandler..ctor (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rkey, System.String basedir) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Win32.KeyHandler.Lookup (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rkey, Boolean createNonExisting) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Win32.UnixRegistryApi.OpenSubKey (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rkey, System.String keyname, Boolean writable) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey (System.String name, Boolean writable) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey:OpenSubKey (string,bool)
  at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeyRegistryStorage.OpenRegistryKey (System.String path, Boolean write) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeyRegistryStorage.Store (System.Byte[] buf, KeyType kt) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Wed Mar 16 10:34:48 2011] [error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
[Wed Mar 16 10:34:48 2011] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was -1
[Wed Mar 16 10:34:48 2011] [error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
[Wed Mar 16 10:34:48 2011] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was -1
... (repeats per page request) ...
```

Comment: Can you post here your apache configuration?

Comment: Upgrade to a newer mono. That error happened when creating the auto generated keys and having no write permissions to the $HOME of the user running apache/mod_mono.

Comment: @yojimbo87 [apache2.conf](http://pastebin.com/1tzwrNb9), [apache site](http://pastebin.com/uSAmck9U). mono 2.10.1 is the latest version of mono, besides the github... @Gonzalo, do you mean compile latest? Also, just to rule it out, chmod 777 on the $home directory doesn't change anything, and as stated above the env var MONO_REGISTRY_PATH is set to a separate directory outside of home, which has also been tried with 777.

Comment: Time to produce a test case and report this in the proper place. See www.mono-project.com/Bugs.